# AVPlayer with sideloaded subtitles breaking when ",SUBTITLES=\"subs\"" is added to the end of the "#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:" lines

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, http-live-streaming, avkit

I am using a modified version of [kanderson-wellbeats' delegate](https://github.com/kanderson-wellbeats/sideloadWebVttToAVPlayer/blob/main/CustomResourceLoaderDelegate.cs) to modify requests as AVKit needs them. All code will be at the bottom of the post. All is well in modifying the requests, making the subtitle playlists, and adding them to the master playlist as they do show up when requesting `AVMediaCharacteristic.legible`, but as soon as I add the line that adds ",SUBTITLES="subs"" to the end of the "#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:" lines, which should add the subtitles to that video track, it won't play anymore. Removing that part makes it possible to select the subtitle track on the playerItem, but the subtitles do not display on the screen.

Note that I am using a custom AVPlayer with AVPlayerLayer instead of AVPlayerViewController as I required a lot more customization; maybe that is the issue?

I know I could probably just add in an overlay with a UILabel for the subtitles, but I'd rather the solution be more native.

**InterceptingAssetResourceLoaderDelegate.swift**
Note: in the subtitle playlist here, there is no comma at the end of the "#EXTINF:(rounded)" line. There seems to be no change in adding it or not, but kanderson-wellbeats said that adding it would cause issues, so it has been removed for now.

```swift
import AVKit

class InterceptingAssetResourceLoaderDelegate: NSObject, AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate {
    private class SubtitleBundle {
        internal init(subtitleDTO: InterceptingAssetResourceLoaderDelegate.SubtitleDTO, playlist: String? = nil) {
            self.subtitleDTO = subtitleDTO
            self.playlist = playlist
        }

        let subtitleDTO: SubtitleDTO
        var playlist: String?
    }

    private struct SubtitleDTO {
        let language: String
        let title: String
        let url: String
    }

    static let videoUrlPrefix = "INTERCEPTEDVIDEO"
    static let subtitleUrlPrefix = "INTERCEPTEDSUBTITLE"
    static let subtitleUrlSuffix = "m3u8"
    private let session: URLSession
    private let subtitleBundles: [SubtitleBundle]

    init(_ subtitles: [VideoSourceEpisodeUrlSubtitle]) {
        self.session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        self.subtitleBundles = subtitles.map({
            SubtitleBundle(subtitleDTO: SubtitleDTO(language: $0.language, title: $0.name, url: $0.url))
        })
    }

    func resourceLoader(
        _ resourceLoader: AVAssetResourceLoader,
        shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource loadingRequest: AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest
    ) -> Bool {
        guard let url = loadingRequest.request.url,
              let dataRequest = loadingRequest.dataRequest else { return true }

        if url.absoluteString.starts(with: Self.subtitleUrlPrefix) {
            guard let targetLanguage = url.host?.split(separator: ".").first,
                  let targetSubtitle = self.subtitleBundles.first(where: { $0.subtitleDTO.language == targetLanguage }),
                  let subtitleUrl = URL(string: targetSubtitle.subtitleDTO.url) else {
                loadingRequest.finishLoading(with: AVError(.unknown))
                return true
            }

            let subtitlePlaylistTask = self.session.dataTask(with: subtitleUrl) { [weak self] data, _, error in
                if let error {
                    loadingRequest.finishLoading(with: error)
                    return
                }
                guard let data, !data.isEmpty, let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else {
                    loadingRequest.finishLoading(with: AVError(.unknown))
                    return
                }

                self?.makePlaylistAndFragments(bundle: targetSubtitle, subtitle: dataString)

                guard let playlistData = targetSubtitle.playlist?.data(using: .utf8) else {
                    loadingRequest.finishLoading(with: AVError(.unknown))
                    return
                }
                dataRequest.respond(with: playlistData)
            }

            subtitlePlaylistTask.resume()
            return true
        }

        guard let newUrl = URL(string: url.absoluteString.replacingOccurrences(of: Self.videoUrlPrefix, with: "")) else { return true }

        if !(
                url.absoluteString.lowercased().hasSuffix(".ism/manifest(format=m3u8-aapl)") ||
                url.absoluteString.lowercased().hasSuffix(".m3u8")
            ) || (
            dataRequest.requestedOffset == 0 && dataRequest.requestedLength == 2 && dataRequest.currentOffset == 0
        ) {
            let newRequest = URLRequest(url: newUrl)
            loadingRequest.redirect = newRequest
            let fakeResponse = HTTPURLResponse(url: newUrl, statusCode: 302, httpVersion: nil, headerFields: nil)
            loadingRequest.response = fakeResponse
            loadingRequest.finishLoading()
            return true
        }

        var correctedRequest = URLRequest(url: newUrl)
        for header in loadingRequest.request.allHTTPHeaderFields ?? [:] {
            correctedRequest.addValue(header.value, forHTTPHeaderField: header.key)
        }

        let masterPlaylistTask = self.session.dataTask(with: correctedRequest) { [weak self] data, _, error in
            if let error {
                loadingRequest.finishLoading(with: error)
                return
            }

            guard let data,
                  let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8),
                  let withSubs = self?.addSubs(to: dataString),
                  let withSubsData = withSubs.data(using: .utf8) else {
                loadingRequest.finishLoading(with: AVError(.unknown))
                return
            }
            dataRequest.respond(with: withSubsData)
            loadingRequest.finishLoading()
        }
        masterPlaylistTask.resume()
        return true
    }

    func addSubs(to dataString: String) -> String {
        guard dataString.contains("#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:") else { return dataString }
        var tracks = dataString.split(separator: "\n").map({ $0.hasPrefix("#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:") ? $0 + ",SUBTITLES=\"subs\"" : $0 })
        tracks.insert(contentsOf: subtitleBundles.map({
            "#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=SUBTITLES,GROUP-ID=\"subs\",LANGUAGE=\"\($0.subtitleDTO.language)\",NAME=\"\($0.subtitleDTO.title)\","
            + "AUTOSELECT=YES,URI=\"\(Self.subtitleUrlPrefix)://\($0.subtitleDTO.language).\(Self.subtitleUrlSuffix)\""
        }), at: tracks.firstIndex(where: { $0.contains("#EXT-X-STREAM-INF") }) ?? tracks.endIndex)
        return tracks.joined(separator: "\n")
    }

    private func makePlaylistAndFragments(bundle: SubtitleBundle, subtitle: String) {
        if let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: #"(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3})"#),
           let timeString = regex.matches(in: subtitle, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: subtitle.count)).last.flatMap({
               (subtitle as NSString).substring(with: $0.range)
           }),
           let hour = timeString.split(separator: ":")[safe: 0].flatMap({ Double($0) }), hour.isFinite,
           let minute = timeString.split(separator: ":")[safe: 1].flatMap({ Double($0) }), minute.isFinite,
           let second = timeString.split(separator: ":")[safe: 2].flatMap({ Double($0) }), second.isFinite {
            let rounded = Int(ceil(hour * 3600 + minute * 60 + second))
            bundle.playlist = [
                "#EXTM3U",
                "#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:\(rounded)",
                "#EXT-X-VERSION:3",
                "#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0",
                "#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD",
                "#EXTINF:\(rounded)",
                bundle.subtitleDTO.url,
                "#EXT-X-ENDLIST"
            ].joined(separator: "\n")
        } else if let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: #"(\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3})"#),
                  let timeString = regex.matches(in: subtitle, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: subtitle.count)).last.flatMap({
                      (subtitle as NSString).substring(with: $0.range)
                  }),
                  let minute = timeString.split(separator: ":")[safe: 0].flatMap({ Double($0) }), minute.isFinite,
                  let second = timeString.split(separator: ":")[safe: 1].flatMap({ Double($0) }), second.isFinite {
            let rounded = Int(ceil(minute * 60 + second))
            bundle.playlist = [
                "#EXTM3U",
                "#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:\(rounded)",
                "#EXT-X-VERSION:3",
                "#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0",
                "#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD",
                "#EXTINF:\(rounded)",
                bundle.subtitleDTO.url,
                "#EXT-X-ENDLIST"
            ].joined(separator: "\n")
        }
    }
}
```

**VideoPlayerViewController.swift**

```swift
    func setSubtitles(to subtitles: [VideoSourceEpisodeUrlSubtitle]) {
        Task {
            if let group = try? await self.playerLayer.player?.currentItem?.asset.loadMediaSelectionGroup(
                for: AVMediaCharacteristic.legible
            ) {
                self.captionsButton.menu = UIMenu(children: [
                    UIAction(
                        title: "None",
                        image: self.currentSubtitleTrack == nil ? UIImage(systemName: "checkmark") : nil
                    ) { [weak self] _ in
                        self?.playerLayer.player?.currentItem?.select(nil, in: group)
                        self?.currentSubtitleTrack = nil
                        self?.setSubtitles(to: subtitles)
                    }
                ] + subtitles.map({ subtitle in
                    UIAction(
                        title: subtitle.name,
                        image: self.currentSubtitleTrack?.url == subtitle.url ? UIImage(systemName: "checkmark") : nil
                    ) { [weak self] _ in
                        let options = AVMediaSelectionGroup.mediaSelectionOptions(from: group.options, with: Locale(
                            identifier: subtitle.language
                        ))
                        if let option = options.first {
                            self?.playerLayer.player?.currentItem?.select(option, in: group)
                            self?.currentSubtitleTrack = subtitle
                            self?.setSubtitles(to: subtitles)
                        }
                    }
                }))
            }
        }
    }
```

**VideoSourceEpisodeUrlSubtitle.swift**

```swift
struct VideoSourceEpisodeUrlSubtitle: Codable {
    let name: String
    let url: String
    let language: String
}
```

Thanks everyone in advance for the help.